# Incremento em vetores Java

Tags: java

estou com dúvidas em relação a algumas linhas de um código, as colocarei em forma de comentário. Segue:

```
     import java.util.Scanner;


        public class Teste131 {

            static final int max = 100000;

                public static void main (String[] args){        


                        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

            int v[] = new int[max];
            int n,x;            

            v[0]=1;

            System.out.println ("Digite um valor para n: ");
            n = entrada.nextInt();

            for (x=1; x<n; x=x+1) {

            /* supondo que foi inserido um valor de "n > x", o comando abaixo atribuirá um valor para a posição onde x=2, pois segundo o laço enquanto "x < n" então "x ++" pois o x incial valia 1 */

            System.out.println ("Digite um valor para v[x]: ");
                v[x] = entrada.nextInt();

            /* caso a entrada acima for por exemplo igual a 1, teremos então até aqui que: v[2] = 1 */

                v[x] *= v[x-1];

            /* caso meus comentários anteriores nesse código estejam corretos, não consigo entender como se chega a resposta do valor de v[x-1] apenas comessa última passagem */

}

            System.out.println ("v[x-1] é igual a: "+ v[x-1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Escrever `v[x] *= v[x-1]` é a mesma coisa que escrever `v[x] = v[x] * v[x-1]`. O valor de v[x-1] já está lá, não é calculado, logo não se pode 'chegar nele'. Imagine o vetor como uma fila, você é a posição 'x' na fila, logo fila[x] = você. Perguntar 'Quem será atendido antes de você?' é o mesmo que perguntar 'Quem é fila[x-1]?', algo que, caso você não seja o primeiro da fila, você sempre será capaz de me dizer.